# Flutter - Color name string to material color

Tags: flutter

In Flutter is there a way to generate a material color from it's name, without creating a full map `Map<String,MaterialColor>`.

In theory, something like this:

```
String colorName = "deepOrange";
MaterialColor color = Colors(colorName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comment, the intention is to save and read back from shared_preferences. In that case, it is better to save and retrieve the color by int value, not by string name, to ensure we always get the color.

- Save: `prefs.setInt("prefered_color", Color.value)`
- Retrieve: `Color c = const Color(prefs.getInt('prefered_color') ?? 0xFF42A5F5);`

---

According to the official [doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Colors-class.html), there's currently no API to perform the function you described. Although it's easy to implement your methodology, I doubt its usefulness in general cases. Also we have to deal with typos or `noSuchColor` errors. But using `const` / `enum` will offer the advantage of compile time error checking.

Comment: I need to save the users material color preference, it needs to be a material color created by flutter and not one created on the spot with hex codes. So I'll create a `const / enum` map.

Comment: Yep, creating a map <String, Color> in your case is the best, though you might want to do proper error handling when getting the color back from preference. Sometimes, the preference is saved across different version of app, and one version might have 5 colors, while the other has only 4 available colors. On the other hand, saves color using `Color.value` and recreate the color with `Color c = const Color(0xFF42A5F5);` will never fail.

Answer (score 2):

I manage to do something like that using the
`Colors.primaries` list ( found in the [`colors.dart` file](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors/primaries-constant.html)):

```dart
    //colors.dart

    /// The material design primary color swatches, excluding grey.
    static const List<MaterialColor> primaries = <MaterialColor>[
      red,
      pink,
      purple,
      deepPurple,
      indigo,
      blue,
      lightBlue,
      cyan,
      teal,
      green,
      lightGreen,
      lime,
      yellow,
      amber,
      orange,
      deepOrange,
      brown,
      // The grey swatch is intentionally omitted because when picking a color
      // randomly from this list to colorize an application, picking grey suddenly
      // makes the app look disabled.
      blueGrey,
    ];
```

So in order to save the colors:

```dart
    Color colorToSave = Colors.indigo;
    prefs.setInt("colorIndex", Colors.primaries.indexOf(colorToSave));
```

To retrieve:

```dart
    MaterialColor colorSaved = Colors.primaries(getInt('colorIndex') ?? 0);
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it.
Let's suppose you want to get the material color for **Colors.blue**

You can use this to get it:-

`MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue)`

For example, to set the background color of an elevated button, a material color should be provided. You can provide a named color like:-

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
    ),
    onPressed: (){},
    child: Text('Press me'),
),
```

Hope helps.